# SuperString theory and mass-energy equivalence

Tags: special-relativity

Please ignore the previous question. As I had said that I knew that the energy released in electron-positron mutual annihilation is 511keV in form of gamma rays. Please reply- What is(or whether there is a) correlation between Electron and Neutrino ( as distinguished from two other forms of  Neutrino-Muon AND Tau).I mean in which respect the three types of neutrino differ from each other

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, most of what you say is contradicted by well-established physics that is backed by innumerable experiments.

It *is* clear what the total destruction of mass means. It means matter-antimatter annihilation into massless radiation. For example, when an electron and a positron collide, 100% of their mass-energy (and their kinetic energy) can get converted into the energy of two (or sometimes more) massless photons. Mass can *completely disappear* and this has been observed countless times.

Light does *not* have mass. At least not the kind of mass modern physicists talk about, which is *Lorentz-invariant mass*.

Electrons do *not* fuse into the nucleus of an atom. If they did, atoms would be unstable.

The energy of the nucleus is very complicated, but it is reasonably well understood. The structure of protons and neutrons is explained by a theory called quantum chromodynamics.

A particle with mass can *never* reach the speed of light, no matter how much energy you give it.

Light is *completely* explainable as an electromagnetic phenomenon.

Neutrinos have *nothing* to do with light.

Making up physics theories can be fun, but good theories need to bear some relationship to facts. So... learn more physics, and then perhaps you can make good theories!

Comment: Thanks for explanations. I did not intend to make any theory. I knew electron-positron thing but electron-neutrino thing is not much clear to me, nor it can be. I have left physics 25 years ago. I am IT-telecom professional. You may well delete my account.